How to solve problem with psycopg2 on Docker?
I have an application image that I am trying to run from Docker with the command
docker run -p 5000:5000 api
Every time I try to run it gets an error
'File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/psycopg2.py", line 690, in import_dbapi
import psycopg2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'.'
Although psycopg2 is installed in the lib directory.
I've tried a lot of solutions, looked through a lot of threads and nothing helps.
ImportError: No module named psycopg2

Can you post also the Dockerfile in here, the problem is that python cannot found the psycopg2 library

In your Dockerfile builder stage, make sure that you install psycopg2. For example, add the following: RUN pip install psycopg2. Or better yet: RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

It seems the problem lies within your Dockerfile.
Python couldn't find the module because it hasn't been installed, it might be installed on your machine but not on the container.
Make sure you install the module on the container at the builder stage.
At the root of your project directory run pip freeze > requirements.txt.
then ensure that your Dockerfile includes the following:
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

